# Given the diameter, draw in pgfplots the circle and its intersection with x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, circles

Given two points, A and B, I want to draw the circle of diameter AB together with its intersection with the X axis.

Intended result is the figure
[image]

I got this with the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rd}{(sqrt(2))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\fs}{(1+sqrt(2))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ss}{(1-sqrt(2))}
  \begin{axis}[
      x=1cm,
      y=1cm,
      axis lines=middle,
      xmin=-1,
      xmax=3,
      ymin=-2,
      ymax=2
    ]
    \node[right] (A) at (0,1) {A} ;
    \node[right] (B) at (2,-1) {B} ;
    \node (V) at (1,-1.2) {label} ;
    \node[left] (C) at (\ss,0.2) {C} ;
    \node[right] (D) at (\fs,0.2) {D} ;
    \draw (1,0) circle[radius=\rd cm] ;
    \addplot[mark=*,color=blue] coordinates {(0,1)} ;
    \addplot[mark=*,color=blue] coordinates {(2,-1)};
    \addplot[mark=*,color=yellow] coordinates {(\fs,0)};
    \addplot[mark=*,color=yellow] coordinates {(\ss,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

While this works, I am not satisfied with it.

What I would like to achieve is that I should provide just the coordinates of A and B, the diameter of the given circle, then everything else should be computed from this.

In particular, I shouldn't compute the center of the circle, its radius and the coordinates of C,D.
Moreover, the dots should be drawn in the node and the letters should be the labels.
Also, the label of the circle should be defined within the circle.

Comment: Providing just A and B won't be enough, as you can draw an infinite number of circles throguh A and B. You need a third point or a third condition, like a symmetry requirement. Which one is it, or should it be?

Comment: @MS-SPO: I said [A,B] has to be the diameter of the circle: there is only one such circle, to my knowledge.

Comment: Ah, now I see. // Why not making it more obvious by stating e.g. "diameter AB as the third condition" ?

Comment: @MS-SPO Yes, maybe it's better. I've added it.

Comment: This is something relatively easy using `tkz-euclide package`, but as I understand you need a solution using pgfplots is't it?

Comment: @MiltosP. : yes, I would prefer, but anyway other solutions could be of interest anyway. I don't know if I can fit them in my problem: what I proposed is an extract of a wider figure. I must say that I do not know the package you mention: I will give a look at it, but if you want to provide a solution, it is surely welcome and if I will be able to fit it in my problem, I will accept it.

Comment: `tkz-euclide` is a package running "under" tikz and its fully compatible with tikz. You can embed any tkz-euclide construction (just you have to load it) in any tikz construction. For your interest, every contraction of tkz-euclide begins with `\begin{tikzpicture}` and ends with `\end{tikzpicture}`. It just has its own internal macros based on those of pfgplots and tikz packages and makes Euclidean Geometry contructions  easiest to made. I can provide you a solution, just give me some time after work and write clearly what exactly want to have after providing these given two points A and B.

Comment: @MiltosP. : please take your time: I am not in a hurry! For my purpose, my figure is enough to go on. I asked just to see if there was a better solution and what you say looks promising. I am using pgfplots because I need to draw also a parabola: if you add a parabola to the picture (let's say y=x^2+x), then  chances are that I can adapt it to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm, y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1,  xmax=3,
ymin=-2,  ymax=2,
x axis line style={name path=xaxis},
]
\coordinate (A) at (0,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,-1);
\draw[name path=circle] let \p1=($ 0.5*(B)+0.5*(A) $), \p2=($ 0.5*(B)-0.5*(A) $), \n1={veclen(\x2,\y2)} in (\p1) circle[radius={\n1}];
\fill[fill=blue] (A) circle[radius=2pt] node[right]{A} (B) circle[radius=2pt] node[right]{B};
\fill[fill=yellow!80!orange, name intersections={of=xaxis and circle}]
 (intersection-1) circle[radius=2pt] node[above left]{C}
 (intersection-2) circle[radius=2pt] node[above right]{D};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle and intersections with x-axis]

Comment: This is very close to what I asked. A few points missed: 1) you deleted `axis on top` : I need it; 2) do I need to put the "label" manually? If I use `node {label}` when drawing the circle, it goes close to the center; 3) what if the circle is tangent to the x axis (for example, `B=(4,4))`? In this case, the (unique) intersection is not found

Comment: Do you mean the `axis on top` option? It is not in your code, -I do not see anything preventing you to add it. For the label, you can use e.g. `...node[below=\n1-0.5cm]{label};`. For the special cases where the circle intersect in no points, or one point, you need to handle them separately with e.g. an `if` statement. If you need it, you can ask a question about that.

Comment: You are right the option `axis on top` was not in my code: it looks like I forgot to copy it from my original figure. My fault. Sorry. In any case, I tried adding it as soon as I saw your code, but I get an error which I can't understand.

Comment: Yes - I see now. When the axis is drawn lastly, we need an other way to name it. You can use e.g. `\path[name path=xaxis] (current axis.left of origin) -- (current axis.right of origin);` as the first thing inside `axis` and delete the `x axis line style={name path=xaxis},` option.

Answer (score 5):

Using `tkz-euclide package` we have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=5]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:1.2]
        \tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=3,ymin=-2,ymax=2,xstep=1,ystep=1] % limits the size of the axes
        \tkzDrawX[>=stealth] % arrow of x-axis
        \tkzDrawY[>=stealth] % arrow of y-axis
        \foreach \x in {-1,1,2,3} \draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below] {\x};% ticks on x-axix
        \foreach \y in {-2,-1,1,2} \draw (0.1,\y) -- (-0.1,\y) node[left] {\y};% tikc on y-axis
        \tkzDefPoints{0/1/A,2/-1/B,-1/0/X,0/0/O} %given points A,B,X(-1,0) and O(0,0)
        \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) %AB diameter-> midpoint K=center 
        \tkzGetPoint{K} %save coordinates of midpoint in name K
        \tkzDrawCircle[thick,black](K,A) %draw circle with center K and R=KA
        \tkzInterLC(O,X)(K,B) %find coordinates of intersection line OX (x-axis) and circle
        \tkzGetPoints{D}{C} %save these coordinates with names D and C, points of intersection
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=yellow](C,D) %draw points C and D
        \tkzDrawPoints[fill=blue](A,B) %fill points A and B with blue color
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](A,B) % label points A and B with letters A and B
        \tkzLabelPoint[above left](C){C}% labels point C
        \tkzLabelPoint[above right](D){D}%labels point D
        \node at (1,-1.2) {label};%labels the circle 
        \draw[color=blue,thick]   plot (\x,{(\x)^2+\x})    node[right] {$f(x) = x^2+x$};% draw parabola, page 344 tikz manual.
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: the output with parabola]

Comment: This is very nice and I will save it for future reference but, actually, I realize it is a bit different from what I was looking for in this case. Anyway, thank you for your time and this interesting piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

With `pstricks` it requires a comparatively short code:

```
    \documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-1.25,-2.25)(3.25,2.25)
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt}
    \psaxes[arrowinset=0.1, ticksize=2pt -2pt, showorigin = false]{->}(0,0)(-1,-2)(3.,2)
    \pnodes(-1,0){X1}(2,0){X2}(1,0){I}(0,1){A}(2,-1){B}
    \uput[r](A){$A$}\uput[r](B){$B$}
    \pstCircleAB{A}{B}
    \psdots[linecolor=RoyalBlue](A)(B)
    \pstInterLC[PointName=none]{X1}{X2}{I}{A}{C}{D}
    \psdots[linecolor=Yellow](C)(D)
    \uput[ul](C){$C$}\uput[ur](D){$D$}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this has to go in a work which already uses an awful amount of packages, so I am not keen on adding another one.